# Version error when uploading Change Set

Tags: change-set, version-control, api-version

I’m trying to deploy custom objects, custom fields, page layouts, compact layouts, Lightning pages and Global value set (global picklist) , when uploading changeset it is giving me API version error as out production platform version 46.0 and SB version is 47.0 , I’m not sure how to bring the version down to 46.0 (There are no Apex triggers/classes in the changeset). Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your sandbox is updated to the next release.The decision whether your org stays on winter 20 or previous release was documented and released.You can read [here](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/08/winter-20-sandbox-preview.html)

[image]

The above chart will be helpful .You will need to know your sandbox instance and take action appropriately before you further build into the org .

***Now what that you have built things in the org which is on 47.0 version?***

There is simple alternative you can take

1)Use salesforce IDE (like [vscode extension for salesforce](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/getting-started/install)) to retrieve the packet by changeset name.You can also try this [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)

2)Change the package.xml version to 46.0 and deploy using the IDE.

Comment: Hi Mohith, Thank you for your help. I'm able to retrieve and download changeset on the workbench but I'm not sure how to change the API version of the package. Any instruction would be really helpful.

Comment: Unzip the folder retrieved. Search for 47.0 and then replace it with 46.0 .That's it .

Comment: Its strange when i edit the package.XML it is showing version 46 in it. but the error message is       "This change set requires the "47.0" or later platform version.
One or more of the listed organizations is on a version incompatible with this change set. You can only select an organization for upload that is running the required version or later."

Comment: May be it has a component thats on a latest release. Try deploying what you have retrieved to the prod org, you will see more meaningful error

Comment: It is not giving me option of choosing my production org at all, so i can't try to deploy.

Comment: I meant deploy using workbench .Workbench you can upload the zip and deploy .

Answer (score 1):

I have just downloaded a changeset in which I have this problem. Now I downloaded it with a Chrome extension, and the package xml in the downloaded zip shows v43. As I do not know how the extension works, I do not know whether the download is a perfect representation of a changeset.

Trying to deploy the zip file, (through sfdx mdapi), I do get an error for my Opportunity Page layout, it contains the Opportunity Contact Role related list, which is not customisable in earlier releases, but with release winter'20/api47, the OpportunityContactRole object has been updated.

Now there might be other changes, and the error provided by SF is not providing this info. So only way to find out what is the issue for you, is to (test) deploy smaller changesets, until you have found the culprit.